# How to add subview to UIViewController pushing UINavigationBar behind

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, addsubview

What I want is as follows:

Basically I have a view controller with navigation bar. There is a menu button as left UINavigationBarItem. On click of menu button list of menu items will animate from top. This is achieved using 'addSubview' method. But menu list is added as subview below navigation bar. I want to add menu list view pushing navigation bar behind menu list view. I dont want to hide navigation bar.

Thanks

Comment: " I want to add menu list view pushing navigation bar behind menu list view." cudnt get u here ?

Comment: Gill, when I add it as subview, it shows navigation bar at top & then menu list view. That is with respect to window menu list view frame's y is status bar height + navigation bar height. How do i set this y pos to only status bar height?

Comment: What is the menu list ?? is it a UIView or a popup ?

Comment: This seems conflicting as "I don't want to hide navigation bar" and "How do I set this y pos to only status bar height" are different (by 44px).

Comment: you can hide ur navigation bar by using [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];

Comment: Gill menu list is actually different controller. I am adding it as childViewController & then addSubview

Comment: hey it is possible to add custom navigationbar in your project..?? then its to easy to add menuview on your navigationbar :)

Answer (score 2):

try:**[`self.navigationController.view** addSubview:xxxView`],this work to my app. Don't use [`self.view addSubview:xxxView`], that can't put the navigation bar behind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried..? bringing your **subview** to front after **adding the subview**

```
//after adding your menu view

 [self.view bringSubViewToFront:menuItemsView];
 [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.navigationController.navigationBar ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not Sure but........ It may be not possible, because if You want to **display** your **menu list** behind your `UINavigationBar` then you need to hide your `UINavigationBar` without hidden `UINavigationBar` **menu list** will always display below the `UINavigationBar`.